# Call static variable from a class that's a dependency of another class?

Tags: php, class, static, scope

Take the following test classes:

```
class A {
    public static $number = 1;
}

class B {
    protected $a;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function getStatic() {
        echo $this->a::$number;
    }
}

$b = new B(new A);
$b->getStatic();
```

Should return 1? I'm not sure, I'm trying to access a static variable off one class after it has been injected as a dependency of another class.

The reason being is, I have a class that gets called asynchronously x times, but it needs a global static that gets updated for the 10 class instances. I do not need 10 instances of the same variable.

So say theres an interator variable as a static, it gets updated by each class and stays one variable. Its not one iterator per class.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm getting the dreaded **syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call static on Class not object.

```
class A {
        public static $number = 1;
}

class B {
        protected $a;

            public function __construct(A $a) {
                $this->a = $a;
            }

            public function getStatic() {
                $class = get_class($this->a);
                echo $class::$number
            }
}

$b = new B(new A);
$b->getStatic();
```

Or Use method in Class A

```
class A {
        public static $number = 1;

        public function getNumber()
        {
            return static::$number;
        }
}

class B {
        protected $a;

            public function __construct(A $a) {
                $this->a = $a;
            }

            public function getStatic() {
                echo $this->a->getNumber();
            }
}

$b = new B(new A);
$b->getStatic();
```

I prefer later.

Comment: Thank you. This is the correct answer for this issue. However I believe my issue is not related to this, but for anyone with this problem, this is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to create a object to access static properties or methods.

Just accessing/echoing A::number from class B doesnt work?

Comment: if you wanted to post comment, work on your reputation. If you wanted to post answer, make it looks so. Do not post comments as answers because of low rep - you will end having your reputation even lower